# Does react re-render the entire table when adding, deleting or inserting a single row?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

During a CRUD operation on an HTML table, is it customary for the entire table to be re-rendered or is it more common for just the affected row to be rendered, e.g., updated, deleted or inserted?

For example, in JQuery (or plain Javascript), you add a row like this without rendering the entire table similar to this:

```
$('#myTable').append('<tr><td>some data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
```

Deleting and updating a specific row is just a bit harder because you usually target the current row but still very easy.  I've never used React and am curious to know if the entire table is generally re-rendered during a CRUD operation or not.  Thank you.

Comment: React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props. Re-render can be caused due to any of the three reasons listed:

Update in State
Update in prop
Re-rendering of the parent component

Comment: @ahmedmoeed, thank you for your response.  I was looking at react reselect and other libraries to see if how you go about affecting a very specific part of a component without re-rendering the entire component.  Do you have any comments/suggestions that can help?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior in react is that when you set state in a component, all of its child components will render too. So most likely, your data is stored in some parent component that's responsible for the entire table, and then when you change that data, the whole table rerenders.

However, two things to note:

1. "Render" in this context just means the react virtual dom process. It may result in few or even no changes to the actual dom
2. Rerendering all children is just the default. If you're having performance issues, you can add code to skip rendering for portions of the component tree that have not changed. In particular, the main tools are React.memo for function components and shouldComponentUpdate for class components.

Comment: Very helpful answer, so then, my guess is that if the actual DOM is not fully rendered, React must use javascript internally to update just the specific portions, much as I do using JQuery but manually in my case?

Comment: When react renders, it calls your components and constructs a "virtual dom". This is a tree of javascript objects which describe what the page is supposed to look like. It then compares the new virtual dom with the previous virtual dom to see what has changed, and then makes targetted changes to the real dom as needed. So if you're adding a row, it may well be that the end result of this process is very similar to your jquery code, adding one `<tr>` to the dom.

Answer (score 1):

React follows a virtual DOM diffing algorithm to determine which components need to be re-rendered. when component's state or props changes react will compare the current virtual DOM tree with previous one and determine which elements have been changed, if the entire table component need to be re-renderd then all of the child components including all of the rows will be re-rendered.

Comment: So then generally speaking, any update, delete or adding a single row operation will update the entire table?  Just want to make sure I understand correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: it will re-render the entire table component when you add,delete or insert a single row if the component is not optiomized to handle such changes in an efficient manner. you could also use the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method to prevent unnecessary re-render and optimize the performance or use libraries like react-table which is light-weight, fast abd extendable data grid build for react. it renders the rows that are visible on the screen, this way avoiding the re-render of the entire table and provides a good performance.